# Create and Append CSV file in Python with header once

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I am creating CSV file using Python code.
I am able to create and store data . But I am unable to Add Header i.e column names in my csv file.
I have Data frame created .
Code for creating and appending csv is as follows:

main_app.py:

````
def handle_data(data):
  msg5 = data.replace("\n"," ").replace("\r"," ").split(",")
  print(msg5)
  d = dict(s.split(':') for s in msg5)
  data_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items())).transpose() 
  data_frame.columns = data_frame.iloc[0]
  data_frame = data_frame.reindex(data_frame.index.drop(0))
  print(data_frame)
  filename = (value_text + time2 + ".csv")
  #print(filename)
  fields = list(data_frame.columns) 
  with open(filename, 'a',newline='') as writeFile:
    writeFile = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writeFile.writerow(fields)
    writeFile.writerows(data_frame.values)

def read_from_port(ser):
 while True:
     reading = ser.readline()
     handle_data(reading.decode("utf-8"))```

read_from_port(serial_port)
````

This code adds the column names every iteration:

Output I get:

```
A  B  C
0  0  0
A  B  C
1  1  1
.......
```

Output I need is:

```
A  B  C
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
.....
```

Can Some one help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not use `data_frame.to_csv()`?

Comment: @DavidBuck, I get one data every iteration in dataframe.

Comment: @DavidBuck, The above code works fine but it doesn't have column names in my csv file. If i remove this line of code  `writeFile.writerow(fields)` .

Comment: You haven't included any iteration in the code above so how can I know that. Assuming `fields` contains your headers (as that's not defined in the code above), if you're calling this code every iteration, that's why they're appearing in every iteration. You just need to make sure you only output the headers once. Or, better, why can't you build the dataframe, then write it out in one go?

Comment: This is why you're asked to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't reproduce your situation from the code you've supplied.

Comment: @DavidBuck, How can i call header only once in this problem?? Can you please help me out with this???

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the loop?

Comment: Please show what *data* passed into function looks like for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv.DictWriter can do that for you!

```
csvfile = csv.DictWriter(writeFile, fieldnames=fields)
csvfile.writeheader()
csvfile.writerows(data_frame.values)
```

Comment: Hi i tried this code but got this error:   `File "C:\Users\I\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys' `

Comment: See comments on the question. Add a loop for csvfile.writerows(), so that each datapoint gets processed.